# Keyboard pass-through from one Ubuntu PC to another?

Tags: networking, keyboard, peripherals

I have two PCs running Ubuntu. Both are on a common LAN and I can even connect them directly to each other with an ethernet cable.

Now, it just so happens that I *hate* the chiclet keyboard on the laptop. I have a mechanical keyboard attached to the desktop, but it's PS/2, so I can't attach it to the laptop.

Is there any way at all I can configure the two so that any keys I press on the keyboard, connected to the desktop, are sent directly to the laptop (including modifiers)?

Comment: Why not a VNC connection? I used it a lot to work on laptops... with key grabbing works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like Synergy. You can get it legally for free from [Github](https://github.com/synergy/synergy/) or buy a version from their [website](http://synergy-project.org/).

> Share one mouse and keyboard between multiple computers.
>   Synergy is free and open source (free as in free speech),
>   meaning you are free to run it and redistribute it with
>   or without changes.

I used an older version of Synergy's predecessor years ago, and did not find it suitable for regular work due to lag and connection problems that occur from time to time. Personally, I would recommend that you invest in a physical hardware KVM switch instead (KVM = "keyboard, video and mouse"). There are numerous models that support both PS/2 and USB keyboards, and some are configurable to allow switching using custom keyboard shortcuts.